# Is it possible to load custom size ad from AdMob into RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob

I've Grid layout for recyclerview with 2 columns, now i want to load ad in this layout, AdMob size documentation mentions custom size ads, but i couldn't find a way to implement this.